# Access session variables in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Is there a way to access the session object/the session variables of a given session (identified by the value of the `_foundation_session` cookie) in the rails console?

Comment: What session store are you using?

Comment: If you're using the default cookie_store, I'd say no way to get this info in console.
If you're using ActiveRecord or Memcached as cache_store, this might be possible.

Comment: We use :dalli_store with memcached. How is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to use ruby-debug:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug

Comment: I don't have time to watch this video right now. Does it just use the "debugger" method? I can't use this because I can't reproduce the issue in development mode but only on the production server and I'd just like to dump the session variables of that one specific session so I can debug the issue.